# Call dropdown list event

Tags: jquery

I need to call below drop down change event somewhere else.How can I do that ?

```
 $('#ddlService').change(function () {

                        if ($(this).val() !== $(this).find('option:eq(0)').attr('value')) {

                            if (petValidation()) {

                                showCommonLayout();
                                defaultLoadMethod();
                            } else {
                                hideCommonLayout();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

I Need to call above event here :

```
$('#providerCancel').on('click', function () {

//I need to call above clouser here

  return false;
});
```

Comment: you can trigger the change event `$('#ddlService').change()` -- the problem is any other registered change event handlers also might get executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
$('#ddlService').trigger('change');
```

or

```
$('#ddlService').change();
```

Comment: Thanks.I used 1 st option.